# Listing rows in columns that have the letter e

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below I have a query that I have been working on for awhile:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE %E%
```

This query is supposed to list every last name that I have in my column that has the letter e in it. The only problem is, is that it is not. I just keep getting an error message that says incorrect syntax by e.

Comment: `WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%E%'` note single quotes

Comment: That's it. I knew I was close but I couldn't quite figure out what. Thank you @Lashane

Comment: Hello , these examples will help you to practice more on LIKE  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need single quotes around the wildcards and letter.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.LAST_NAME LIKE '%E%'
```